# How can we control the size of a special character?

Tags: html, css

I want to use the following character in a page:

```
<div>&#9660;</div>
```

(it's a down arrow character). Is there a way to change its size? I'm not even sure how its initial size is determined anyway - can we apply a font size to it? Or is there some css scale attribute we can apply to it?

Or can I specify its exact width/height in pixels?

Thank you

Comment: Font size will work, you'll most likely get distortion and any spaces beside other words will get bigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS to control it just like any other text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-size

Answer (score 2):

The size of the character is determined by the font family and the font size. Both of them can be set as usual in CSS, with the `font-family` and `font-size` properties (or even using old-fashioned HTML `font` tag). Setting `font-size` different from other text on the same line tends to cause uneven line spacing, but this does not matter if you are using the character in a block of its own, as the `div` markup suggests.

The character denoted by `&#9660;` is not an arrow but U+25BC BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE “▼”. Its relative size (relative to font size) [varies](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/fontsupport.htm) a lot by font family, so you should primarily consider the font family choice, using a reasonable list of font families (with comparable size for this character), and only if needed consider font size too.

Comment: Correct Answer..!!

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other font is controlled

```
<div style="font-size:x-large">&#9660;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you control the size of any other character. Just set the font size.